# Android Studio Logcat not showing anything

Tags: java, android

I implemented all techniques using stackoverflow but none of them worked for me.

i have android studio version 2.2.i have enable adb integration as well as DDMS setting etc all solutions. i restarted logging and restart app,Android studio and Laptop restart as well but  nothing worked for me. i am attaching my error dialog Verbose and info images with this post.
    [image: error Dialog] 
    [image: Verbose]
    [image]

Comment: Please copy past code snippets and avoid posting screenshots of code. Posting screenshots makes it unnecessary hard to read your code and to reproduce your problem (Especially when the screenshots are in some kind of random order like you did).

Comment: Have you try tag search?

Comment: No i didn't try @GuruTeja

Comment: No i didn't try @anonymous

Comment: Then try Search near the Info drop down . Like "tag:as"

Comment: Why are you trying to do? What are the results and how do they differ from what you want?

Comment: Please post code here directly, not s screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio logcat not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815356/android-studio-logcat-not-working)

Answer (score 12):

1. File ->Invalidate Cache[image: Invalidate Cache]

2.Restart your phone or emulator

3. Run. It should work

Comment: Yes! Restarting the phone, too!

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was not an android studio problem but a phone problem - **try to restart your phone** or emulator.

Answer (score 5):

Kill ADB from Task Manger, And run an application and check filter as 'Show only selected application' in Android monitor.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this issue by enabling "Use libusb backend" option in Android Studio -> Preferences -> Debugger -> Android Debug Bridge (adb).[image]

Comment: Doing this wouldn't allow the apk to be installed on my phone. Maybe this works for emulators only?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved that issue through applying no filter at filter section.

Answer (score 0):

For me simply restarting Android Studio solved the issue. I was even able to see the logs which were hidden to me previously.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved by simply deattaching and attaching my mobile phone and hope so this will work for all of you

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using Log methods without properly initializing the TAG parameter.