# Android studio Logcat won't show stacktrace on app crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-logcat

I just did a reinstall of Android Studio with 3.1.1 and my initial problems were solved, however, now I can't see my errors in the logcat. I've selected no filter in the logcat settings, but it still doesn't show them.
[Logcat settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BymkS.png)

This is my **app level gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.akhilsukh01.earthquakepreparednessproject"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

        implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0'
        implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
}
```

This is my **project level gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I know there are many duplicates in the app level gradle file but removing any of them creates and error that I can't fix(because of the log). It worked while I had Firebase Crashlytics, but I can't remove it either without the build failing. I would also appreciate help in cleaning up my gradle files and removing unnecessary Firebase implementations.

I get this at the end of the log

```
read: unexpected EOF!
```

EDIT1] this is the output from the **run** toolbar.

```
04/19 14:15:55: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.akhilsukh01.earthquakepreparednessproject C:\Users\akhil\Documents\Apps\EarthquakePreparednessProject\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.akhilsukh01.earthquakepreparednessproject/com.akhilsukh01.earthquakepreparednessproject.IntroHome" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 5201 on device oneplus-one_a2005-ad12fad1
```

EDIT2] Okay, I ran my app on an emulator and everything worked perfectly. I've narrowed it down to my phone being the problem. I think its because Studio is receiving too much data at once causing an error. More specifically this one

[logcat crashes with read: unexpected EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689930/logcat-crashes-with-read-unexpected-eof)

But i still can't fix it.

Comment: Are you using multiple devices? If so, you might need to change the output device in the top left of the logcat. Edit: Actually, on second thought, try selecting the "run" option at the very bottom of the logcat (the one with the green play button next to it"

Comment: It doesn't change during the crash, i've updated my post to show the output.

Comment: @Sukhthrankar Sorry about that, my suggestion was wrong anyway. Got my logcat windows mixed up.

Comment: did you try to filter your logcat with an specific package name?

Comment: yes, i tried that. Do you think it has something to do with this                     "    read: unexpected EOF!" at the end of the partial log